# Where does Android Studio 3.1 store generated apk/aar files?

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

After updating to Android Studio to version 3.1, I do not get generated apk/aar files from build/outputs directory.
Can anyone has idea where these files actually located? 
And yes I am **getting it by manually generating** from gradle tasks from the same location.
Well I get apk "`build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug`" here. But no clue about aar from my library project.

Comment: it generates apk for me in build->outputs->apk itself

Comment: I am getting into build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug

Comment: click on build -> buildApk  , or try disabling instant run

Comment: My AARs show up in `build/outputs/aar/`, but I work with Instant Run disabled.

Comment: try after enabling instant run. this is mysterious :d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have concluded this:
After updating Gradle tools version to 3.1.0 , you are not able to get the debug apk directly from build folder because of instant apk run support it generates slice apks in folder `'\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices'`
If you want full apk then you may need to downgrade
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` 
to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

It will still builds a full apk but don't support instant run.

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can still generate the APK.

Go to **Build -> Build APK(s)**. APK will be generated and a notification will appear in the Android Studio.